# WPDB SQL query with prepare() returning variable, not db value

Tags: database, wpdb, sql, variables, bbpress

I have been trying to get this to work for awhile now and I cannot seem to get any farther on my own.  It seems to work fine as a normal SQL query but not within the WP framework using [prepare()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).  Basically I am trying to insert a PHP variable within the SQL query but instead of returning the value I SELECTed, the function returns the value of the variable.

I have searched for others having the same problem but most of them are dealing with problems with LIKE and the % wildcard.  I cannot figure out what my problem is.

I am using a bbPress variable which is the forum id.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
global $wpdb;
$countquery = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare(
"SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = '_bbp_forum_subforum_count' 
AND post_id=%d", bbp_forum_id()));
echo $countquery;
```

Comment: If you run `var_dump( $wpdb->prepare(
"SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = '_bbp_forum_subforum_count' 
AND post_id=%d", bbp_forum_id() ) );`, does it look the way you expect?  Does `bbp_forum_id()` return a number, or a string that contains a number?  If the latter, try using `(int) bbp_forum_id()`.

Comment: The loop returns the same using (int) or not with var_dump [the first number changes, which is the what bbp_forum_id returns]:  `518string(93) "SELECT meta_value FROM cd_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_bbp_forum_subforum_count' AND post_id=0"`

Comment: And what do you get if you just echo bbp_forum_id(); ?

Comment: the id of the forum, i.e. 518, 520, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `bbp_forum_id()` will directly `echo` its value, you want to use `bbp_get_forum_id()` which will `return` the value for use in the context of an API call.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
global $wpdb;
$forum_id = bbp_get_forum_id();
$countquery = $wpdb->get_var( 
    $wpdb->prepare(
       "SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
        WHERE meta_key = '_bbp_forum_subforum_count' 
        AND post_id=%d",
    $forum_id 
    ) 
);
echo $countquery;
```

For some reason the `bbp_forum_id()` within the  `$wpdb->prepare()` is either returning `0` or a non-decimal value.  (Some quick experimentation shows me that `[sprintf()](http://php.net/sprintf)`, on which `$wpdb->prepare()` is based, will interpolate `0` into the returned string if the `%d` value is not a number.)

**Edited** -- uses `bbp_get_forum_id()` per @Milo's answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Milo's different function ended up being easier to implement.

Comment: NP. Milo's is the correct answer; in fact I've changed mine to use the proper `bbp_get_forum_id()` function in case anyone stumbles across it later.